# Amazon Rekognition for text detection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have images of receipts and I want to store the text in the images separately. Is it possible to detect text from images using Amazon Rekognition?

Answer (score 14):

Update from November 2017:

> Amazon Rekognition announces real-time face recognition, Text in Image
>   recognition, and improved face detection

Read the announcement here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-rekognition-announces-real-time-face-recognition-text-in-image-recognition-and-improved-face-detection/

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Quite right! [Amazon Rekognition Text in Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detection.html) "can detect text in images and convert it into machine-readable text". However, it can't do full-page OCR.

Comment: There is a 50 word limit on AWS Rekognition OCR. :(

Comment: @Vingtoft that was a surprise for me as well, so Tesseract+Lambda to the rescue - https://twitter.com/vladholubiev/status/1022607436274970624

Answer (score 6):

No, Amazon Rekognition not provide Optical Character Recognition (OCR).

At the time of writing (March 2017), it only provides:

- Object and Scene Detection
- Facial Analysis
- Face Comparison
- Facial Recognition

There is no AWS-provided service that offers OCR. You would need to use a 3rd-party product.

Comment: As of Feb 2018, OCR capabilities can now be demo'ed in Amazon Web Services e.g. at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/home?region=us-east-1#/text-detection

Answer (score 3):

Amazon doesn't provide an OCR API. You can use Google Cloud Vision API for Document Text Recognition. It costs $3.5/1000 images though. To test Google's open this link and paste the code below in the the test request body on the right.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate

```
{
   "requests": [
     {
       "image": {
         "source": {
           "imageUri": "JPG_PNG_GIF_or_PDF_url"
         }
       },
       "features": [
         {
           "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may get better results with [Amazon Textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/) although it's currently only available in limited preview.

It's possible to detect [text in an image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detection.html) using the [AWS JS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Rekognition.html#detectText-property) for [Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/) but your results may vary.

```
/* jshint esversion: 6, node:true, devel: true, undef: true, unused: true */

// Import libs.
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const axios = require('axios');

// Grab AWS access keys from Environmental Variables.
const { S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, S3_REGION } = process.env;

// Configure AWS with credentials.
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: S3_REGION
});

const rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition({
  apiVersion: '2016-06-27'
});

const TEXT_IMAGE_URL = 'https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/text';

(async url => {

  // Fetch the URL.
  const textDetections = await axios
    .get(url, {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })

    // Convert to base64 Buffer.
    .then(response => new Buffer(response.data, 'base64'))

    // Pass bytes to SDK
    .then(bytes =>
      rekognition
        .detectText({
          Image: {
            Bytes: bytes
          }
        })
        .promise()
    )
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('[ERROR]', error);
      return false;
    });

  if (!textDetections) return console.log('Failed to find text.');

  // Output the raw response.
  console.log('\n', 'Text Detected:', '\n', textDetections);

  // Output to Detected Text only.
  console.log('\n', 'Found Text:', '\n', textDetections.TextDetections.map(t => t.DetectedText));

})(TEXT_IMAGE_URL);
```

See more examples of using Rekognition with NodeJS in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033668/5623301).

Answer (score 1):

```
 public async Task<List<string>> IdentifyText(string filename)
        {
            // Using USWest2, not the default region
            AmazonRekognitionClient rekoClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient("Access Key ID", "Secret Access Key", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);            
            Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image img = new Amazon.Rekognition.Model.Image();
            byte[] data = null;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                data = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            }
            img.Bytes = new MemoryStream(data);   

            DetectTextRequest dfr = new DetectTextRequest();
            dfr.Image = img;
            var outcome = rekoClient.DetectText(dfr);

            return outcome.TextDetections.Select(x=>x.DetectedText).ToList();           
        }
```

Comment: Please add a comment to your answer, explaining your code